# How to hide the “Paste” menu on Safari browser when using `navigator.clipboard.readText()` in the button click handler?

Tags: javascript, safari, webkit

I'm trying to read the clipboard data using the `navigator.clipboard.readText()` in the button click handler:

```js
<body>
    <h1>How to paste text</h1>
    <p><button type=button>Paste</button></p><textarea></textarea>
    <script>
        const pasteButton = document.querySelector("button");
        pasteButton.addEventListener("click", (async () => {
            try {
                const e = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
                document.querySelector("textarea").value += e;
                console.log("Text pasted.")
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log("Failed to read clipboard. Using execCommand instead.");
                document.querySelector("textarea").focus();
                const t = document.execCommand("paste");
                console.log("document.execCommand result: ", t)
            }
        }));
    </script>
</body>
```

We can use the following link to check the demo page using the above code: https://web.dev/patterns/clipboard/paste-text/demo.html

The demo page works fine when clicking the "Paste" button on the Chrome browser. But, it shows the "Paste" menu when clicking the "Paste" button on the Safari browser.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQdMd.png)

Only when clicking the "Paste" menu on the Safari browser, the clipboard data is pasted into the text box.

**So, I'd like to know how to hide the "Paste" menu on Safari browser when using `navigator.clipboard.readText()` in the button click handler.**

Thanks.

I expect that I need to hide the "Paste" menu on the Safari browser.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/133001 / https://webkit.org/blog/10855/async-clipboard-api/